# Best approach to get multiple keys from an immutable map?

Tags: ecmascript-6, immutable.js

What is the best way to get multiple values from an immutable map?

```
const example = new Map({
    id: 1,
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Smith',
    age: '99',
    gender: 'M',
    children: new List([7,8,10]),
});
```

Using `toJS()` has been an approach:

```
const {
    first,
    last,
    age,
    gender
} = example.toJS();
```

But if I were to pull in children it would no longer be an immutable list.

Using `get()`:

```
const first = example.get('first');
const last = example.get('last');
...
```

This maintains the type of children, but seems like extra cycles and key strokes.

Any thoughts?

**I know this can be an opinionated question, but I'm looking for something with merit, please include stats (key strokes, cycles) to support your answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would probably just stick with the `.get()`s, but if you want to be able to use destructruing, you could try the [`.toJSON()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/toJSON) method. It's like `.toJS()` but it only does a shallow conversion to either an object or an array. You could also use [`.toObject()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/toObject) or [`.toArray()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/toArray) if you know what type you'd like to turn it into (which you must if you're destructuring it).

```js
const m = Immutable.fromJS({
  a: {a2: 'a3'},
  b: [1, 2, {f: 'f'}],
});

const { a, b } = m.toJSON();
console.assert(Immutable.isImmutable(a) && Immutable.isImmutable(b));
console.log('a =', a);
console.log('b =', b)
const [ c, d, e ] = b.toArray();
console.assert(c == 1 && d == 2 && Immutable.isImmutable(e));
const { f } = e.toObject();
console.assert(f === 'f');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

I made a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/immutable-multi-get/1) since you mentioned you wanted stats. For me using Chrome 63 on a MacBook Pro, `.get` is about 3x as fast as `.toJSON`

Comment: Cool, did you happen to check performance of .toJS vs .toJSON vs .get?

Comment: I didn't put `toJS()` in the test because it didn't really do what you wanted. I'm pretty sure it would be much slower though since it has to convert the entire nested structure and not just the first layer. `toJSON` will have the same performance as `toObject` or `toArray` because it's actually just an alias.